# How can I align graphs in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, information-graphics

I just started learning how to make graphs in Illustrator. I’d like to be able to align my graphs just like I’m able to with other groups of objects. However, when the Selection tool is chosen and a graph is selected, I don’t see any alignment options in the Control panel. Also, clicking the alignment options in the Align panel doesn’t do anything.

So, is there any way to align graphs?

(In case it helps, I’m using Illustrator 26.0.1 on macOS 11.6.1.)

EDIT: I think I’ve figured it out. Apparently, graphs don’t function like normal grouped objects in Illustrator. Because of this, the alignment or transform options don’t work. If you really need to use those options, you have to first ungroup the graph. However, doing so will remove the ability to change the graph’s style, data, and design, so it’d be a good idea to duplicate the graph before ungrouping.

Comment: Align them to what??? And what *kind* of graph?

Comment: @Scott, I think I’ve solved my own problem. Check the edit I made to the question. But thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh.. okay. You *can* answer your own question. I'm using an older version of AI.. I'd have thought by v26 they'd have fixed that annoying issue. "newer" isn't always "better".

Comment: @Scott Yeah, it is kind of annoying. There are a lot of cool things you can do with graphs in Illustrator, but there are still frustrating limitations that seem like pretty basic things to me! As for answering my own question, I didn’t see that option at first. I’ll go ahead and do that when I get a chance later.

Comment: Protip make your own graphing routines. Not only does it give you options. But also it is one if the easiest things you will ever program since all you need is do straightforward and covered in high school.

Comment: Protip: [Look at this graph](https://youtu.be/sIlNIVXpIns)